# How do I prevent Blender adding an index-suffix to the objects' names?

Tags: objects, import

My problem is that whenever I delete all objects (selecting all objects and pressing 'Delete' then selecting 'Delete' from the drop-down menu) and import them back, the objects' names get an "index suffix", e.g. ".001".

For example, I import an .obj file, and there is an object in that file with the name "TableA". I delete it, import the same file, and now it has the name "TableA.001". I'm using a script afterwards which references the tables with their "original" name, so it's a little bit annoying I have to remove those indexes. Is there a way to circumvent this behavior?

Also, some sort of explanation would be nice - why does the program feel the urge to add that index though there is no existing object with the original name (because it has been deleted)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you delete an object, not all information about it will be deleted. Its **mesh data** will remain in the file. So if you want to delete the **mesh data**, open **Outliner** in **Orphan data** mode and click on **Purge All** - it will delete all **mesh data** that are not used in the scene, and free names.

[image: Screen shot highlighting location of "purge all" button]

Normally, object and mesh data can use different names, but the obj-import script makes these names the same. That's the reason why a new object gets the  old name, but obj-import gets a new one.

Comment: I see, indeed there were bunch of meshes in the file, but "Purge All" seems like does the job. Thanks!